# Getting inner digit after a tag and in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is some content

```
<p class="someclass">
    slerert укенукен werwert wert <br>
    1. вапр апоц вкен 8 ролгшщ 9 ар<br>
    3. ап 7 варер прпрпр<br>
    ...
</p>
```

Is it possible to change the style of digit coming next after `<br>` and not touching other digits?
We can select something like `$(p.someclass br)` but how to get the following digit (to change its style)?

Comment: Can you explain what "change it's style" means?  Please provide an example of what you've tried and the desired output.

Comment: @billynoah for example, to transform `1.` into `<b>1.<b>`

Comment: @billynoah the above is true for the `3.` also

Comment: If you put "1." into a span tag, that may help.

Comment: @derloopkat the idea is we can not know how many digits will be there in the content

Comment: that's okay, but can you add tags into your HTML?

Comment: @derloopkat this content generated server side so I thought to make other processing in client side

Comment: there are good ways and bad ways to do things.  derloopcat is trying to help you do things the good way by asking if you have access to the markup.  if you do not, then trying to parse this frontend is possible, however it is not the best way

Comment: I suggest using CSS and span tags to bracket the text that is to get special style attributes as opposed to the use of JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: @thinker listen to JohnH.  he knows what he is talking about

Answer (score 3):

well, you can maybe parse the html and then replace what you want... but it is pretty ugly.

```js
var text = $('.someclass').html();
text = text.replace(/^\s*(\d\.)/gm, '<b>$1</b>')

$('.someclass').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="someclass">
    slerert укенукен werwert wert <br>
    1. вапр апоц вкен 8 ролгшщ 9 ар<br>
    3. ап 7 варер прпрпр<br>
</p>
```

Comment: This one gets my vote. It's a better answer than mine because it finds lines that start with the digit followed by the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex for this. Query the paragraph through `document.querySelector`.

Then search for all instances that match a number followed by a dot. The regex for this is `/\d+\./g`.

- `\d` indicates a digit between 0 and 9
- `\+` will match one or more digits
- `\.` Periods must be escaped in regex

We will simply use the `replace` method to replace these instances and wrap them in `<b>` tags to make them bold

```js
var par = document.querySelector(".someclass");
var numbers = par.innerHTML.match(/\d+\./g); 
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    par.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.replace(numbers[i], "<b>" + numbers[i] + "</b>");
}
```

```html
<p class="someclass">
    slerert укенукен werwert wert <br>
    1. вапр апоц вкен 8 ролгшщ 9 ар<br>
    3. ап 7 варер прпрпр<br>
    ...
</p>
```

Comment: I'm going to admit something. This is not an ideal regex. Because it doesn't match lines that start with a digit followed by a dot. I tried something like `/^\s?\d+\./gm` but it said cannot read property length of undefined. Could anyone help me improve this regex

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do it. But it may help:

```js
var htmlSplits = $(".someclass").html().split("<br>");

var modifiedSplits = htmlSplits.map(function( split ){
  var str = split.replace(/\\n/g, "").trim();
  console.log( str );
  var regex = /^\d/;

  var matches = str.match(regex);
  if( matches )
    return str.replace( matches[0], "<b>"+matches[0]+"</b>");
  else
    return str;
});//forEach()

var updatedHTML = modifiedSplits.join("<br>");
$("#updated-text").html( updatedHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="someclass">
    slerert укенукен werwert wert <br>
    1. вапр апоц вкен 8 ролгшщ 9 ар<br>
    3. ап 7 варер прпрпр<br>
</p>

<p id="updated-text">
</p>
```

Comment: was in the middle of writing up something very similar.  this will work, but why you would do things this way I can't imagine

Comment: @McHat You mean the longer way I have taken to replace the digits? Actually I am not very good with regex so, solved it this way. Patrick above has implemented the solution in much succinct way.

Comment: no, I mean the right answer is to fix the markup.  hacking it up this way is dirty, ugly, and wrong.  it does answer his original question though

Comment: yes you're right @McHat. But he may be getting this html from somewhere (server)  in this format and it may not be able to control it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *Vanilla JS* that uses `Array.prototype.forEach` to loop and add the *numbering* nodes and replacing the *numbering texts* - see demo below:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".someclass br"), function(e, i) {

  // extract the numbering from the text
  var el = document.createElement('b');
  var text = (/^\s*\d./).exec(e.nextSibling.nodeValue);

  // remove the numbering from the next node
  e.nextSibling.nodeValue = e.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/^\s*\d./, '');

  // create the numbering element
  if (text) {
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text[0].trim()));
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(el, e.nextSibling);
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="someclass">
  slerert укенукен werwert wert
  <br>1. вапр апоц вкен 8 ролгшщ 9 ар
  <br>3. ап 7 варер прпрпр
  <br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the numbers with decimals in front and change those to `<b>$1</b>`:

```
var p = $('.someclass').html();

p = p.replace(/([0-9]\.)/g, "<b>$1</b>");                   

$('.someclass').html(p);
```